# onClick() imageview shows a gray background

Tags: android, imageview

I have a simple ImageView with transparent image with onclick function:

```
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/btnLL"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/options"
    android:onClick="ClickSettings"/>
```

The problem is, when I click (touch) the image, a gray square background appears for a second and then it disappears. Seems like some click effect.

How can I remove this?

I tried to use ImageButton instead, also tried to use background from xml selector in drawable :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

but the gray background is still appearing when I click the image.

Comment: If you want to disable the selector on `ImageView` just use `android:background="@null"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another state to your button and remap it with a transparent background :

```
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

You can check all the states here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Best